# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string during update only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been searching for a resolution for a long time now and just can't seem to formulate a query that brings back the resolution so as a last resort I have posted here.
I have a SQL server table with a varchar column that has the date and time stored in this format

```
"1/1/2013 11:38:31 PM Some other text"
```

I needed this date and time portion of this data to be stored in another column in datetime datatype.  So I created a new column called DateTimeLog of type datetime.

I then used left to chop off the extra text and convert to change the value to datetime format and got the result I would expect.

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME,(rtrim(left(olddate, 21)))) from mytable
results:
"2013-01-01 23:38:31.000"
```

So far, so good.  this is what I would expect.  My troubles begin when I attempt to update my new datetime column with the results of this CONVERT statement.

```
update mytable
SET DateTimeLog = CONVERT(DATETIME,(rtrim(left(olddate, 21)))) from mytable
```

I get the infamous "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" error message.

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I have also attempted to use cast

```
update mytable
SET DateTimeLog = (cast(CONVERT(DATETIME,(rtrim(left(oldtable, 21)))) as datetime)) from mytable
```

the error persists.  As best I can tell the convert is working correctly because I can see the result set from a select, but getting that result into a new column has eluded me thus far.
thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your string isn't going to consistently be 21 characters long. Your sample data shows a single character month and a single character date. What if it's, say, `12/13/2018`?

That said, you need a more robust way to isolate that timestamp. I used a `PATINDEX` to capture the position of the last colon in the time component, with a couple of regexes in there to account for the numbers & the AM/PM thing. Then I added 6 to it to get to the end of the string of interest.

This seems to work:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (olddate VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @t
  (
    olddate
  )
VALUES
  ('12/13/2018 11:38:31 PM Some other text')
  ,('1/1/2018 11:38:31 PM Some other text');

SELECT CAST(LEFT(olddate,PATINDEX('%:[0-9][0-9] [AP]M%', olddate)+6) AS DATETIME)
FROM @t;
```

Results:

```
+-------------------------+
| 2018-12-13 23:38:31.000 |
| 2018-01-01 23:38:31.000 |
+-------------------------+
```

Rextester: https://rextester.com/BBPO51381 (although the date format's a little funky on the output).

Comment: I would make only one suggestion... use try_cast() or try_convert() considering the risks of string conversions.  +1 .... oops.  didn't see the 2008

Comment: Yeah. Lots of better options with higher versions.

Comment: thanks I'll give it a try and report back.  I thought 21 characters covered me for double digit dates but i will verify.  the output tests correct without error when I look at the result set in SSMS, the failure only happens when I try to take that converted value and update the table.

Comment: You might be losing an occasional 'M' picking up the first character of the stray text at the end with a static value. I hope it helps!

Comment: Eric, I think you are on to something.  I can select up to 13700 rows before I get the conversion error.  my problem lies in something beyond that number of rows.  trying to find it is going to prove difficult I believe.

Comment: Parsing strings is seldom pretty. That's a rough data model you're stuck with.

Comment: ok here is what I have discovered.  I only need to remove the last 6 right most characters to have a complete string with the time.  I think I'm supposed to use rtrim for that but I have only ever used that for removing spaces.  is there way to truncate the last 6 chars?  something like the exact reverse of what I am doing with the left function?

Comment: my issue is resolved.  I replaced the left(olddate, 21) with left(olddate, len(olddate) -6